# When I do pip --version it show the error as ImportError: No module named pyparsing

Tags: python, linux, terminal, pip, package

I tried installing/uninstalling **pyparsing** as well and it does not work. I am stuck with this and I have to install additional libraries as well.

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/home/rachana/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resour‌​ces/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
File "/home/rachana/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/‌​requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
ImportError: No module named pyparsing
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `easy_install pyparsing`?

Comment: Its not working still ! tried all possibilites

Comment: Please include the _exact_ error messages in your question

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/rachana/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/home/rachana/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
ImportError: No module named pyparsing

Comment: What does `easy_install pyparsing` return?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/rachana/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/home/rachana/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
ImportError: No module named pyparsing

Comment: The same error.

Comment: Then you'll need to [install](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Download+and+Installation) `pyparsing` manually.

Comment: Got it thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried installing it _from source_, as shown in the 'Installing' section?

Comment: Yeah downloaded the zip file and ran the same

Comment: In case that doesn't work, read [harshvchawla's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42897868/7812406). It worked for me!

Answer (score 19):

I'm had the same problem and resolved it. 
Here is you can see that pip not working properly (without any additional parameters).

```
root@notebook:/home/ci# pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
```

Okay, so first that we may do is installing broken dependency:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/3c/ec/a94f8cf7274ea60b5413df054f82a8980523efd712ec55a59e7c3357cf7c/pyparsing-2.2.0.tar.gz
gunzip pyparsing-2.2.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf pyparsing-2.2.0.tar
cd pyparsing-2.2.0 && python setup.py install
```

After it mising dependency will be installed from sources.

Trying to using pip one more time:

```
root@rundeck.euovh01.un.private:/tmp/pyparsing-2.2.0# pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    import appdirs
ImportError: No module named appdirs
```

This is the next problem. And you can fix it more quickly:

```
root@notebook:/home/ci# python -m pip install appdirs
Downloading/unpacking appdirs
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: appdirs
Successfully installed appdirs
Cleaning up...
```

After that my pip was successfully repaired. 
Kind regards.

Comment: Thanks! You're a life saver. I had to run the install commands with `sudo`, the otherwise this solution worked perfectly.

Comment: awesome! do you know what caused this error in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [@Oleg Mykolaichenko answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42721488), but using pip:

```
[sudo] pip install pyparsing

[sudo] pip install appdirs
```

Comment: This did not work. The problem is that `pip` is broken because `pyparsing` is missing, so running `pip install pyparsing` will just produce the same `ImportError: No module named pyparsing` error.

Answer (score 0):

ah! I was stuck with for an hour and found this out

```
pip3 install pyparsing
```